# After Facebook Follow button get download url in my website using php

Tags: javascript, facebook, button, download, get

I am really stuck please any body help me. After click on Facebook Follow button from my website he or she will follow me on facebook and they get a download url in my website using php .if he or she not follow me then he dont get the download url.

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script>(
  function(d, s, id) { 
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
    if(d.getElementById(id)) 
      return; 
    js = d.createElement(s); 
    js.id = id; 
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=601785493190008&version=v2.0" ‌​; 
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: can you post the code you have used for this?

Comment: Sir i used facebook developer api but i can not able to chage by my custom code..

Comment: <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=601785493190008&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>